# How to delete some rows which keys has the same prefix from a table in SQLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

simple table with

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb (id TEXT NOT NULL, json TEXT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id))`

insert 4 rows into the table, looks like:

`akey1, avalue1
akey2, avalue2
bkey1, bvalue1
bkey2, bvalue2`

in android, I execute delete with `like`:

```
final SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

boolean result = false;
database.beginTransaction();  
try{
    database.delete(tableName," id like ? ", new String[]{"akey%"})
    database.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
    result = true;
}catch(Exception e){
    result = false;
}finally{
    database.endTransaction(); 
}
```

I found that, the two rows: `akey1` and `akey2` were NOT be removed.

If I run `DELETE FROM tb  where id like  'akey%'` with sqlitebrowser, It is OK.

What's wrong for that?

Comment: Remove the `catch`. Do you get an error?

Comment: @CL. No. I do not get exception

Comment: Check my answer i updated that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be you missing single qoutation around like statement and it may work if you add single qoutations around your like condition. Like so:

```
database.delete(tableName," id like '?';", new String[]{"akey%"});
```

but anyway The "?" Placeholder is a little buggy some times.

You better to construct the statement on your own and send null as args like below:

```
 String likeCondition = "akey%";
database.delete(tableName," id like '"+ likeCondition + "';", null);
```